# Running Total Measure for Project Milestones

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I have a SSAS 2012 cube that has project name, milestone name and milestone date dimensions.  The basic measure is dollars spent.  I need an additional calculated measure of the cumulative dollars for a project spent through each milestone date.

```
Example of Data:
Project Milestone Milestone Date Spent Running Total  
A       1         1/1/2015         10      10  
A       2         2/23/2015        35      45  
A       3         4/5/2015          4      49  
B       1         6/7/2015          2       2
B       2         9/7/2015         49      51
```

The milestone date dimension is referenced through the Milestone dimension. Any suggestions on how to create the calculated measure would be appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying till now?

Comment: aggregate({[Project].[Project Name].CurrentMember, [Milestones].[Milestone].Members(0):[Milestones].[Milestone].CurrentMember})

Comment: @chuckn better to use `Sum` - dollars will be additive so unnecessary to use `Aggregate`. Are you saying that this snippet of mdx is what you are trying but is not working?

Comment: I came up with this recursive solution:  
with MEMBER [Measures].[rnTotal] AS  
iif(([Milestones].[Work Plan].PrevMember.Parent is [Milestones].[Work   Plan].CurrentMember.Parent),([Measures].[rnTotal], [Milestones].[Work   Plan].CurrentMember.PrevMember)  + [Measures].[Spent], [Measures].  [Spent])  

Workplan is a hierarchy of project and milestone.  
It works fine with Project and Milestone Columns.  When I add the  Milestone Date Column, it returns all milestone dates up to the  milestone.  I am shooting for just the milestone date as shown in the  example data snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example against AdvWrks:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[rnTotal] AS 
    Sum
    (

        (NULL : [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember)
      * 
        [Product].[Category].CurrentMember
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[rnTotal] ON 0
 ,
    [Product].[Category].[Category]
  * 
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[6]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2007]&[6]
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: That works fine for Adventure Works where the Date dimension is tied to the OrderDateKey on the InternetSales Fact.  It doesn't seem to work when I try something this in my case:
with MEMBER [Measures].[rnTotal] AS
sum((null:[Milestone_Date].[Date].currentmember) * [Project].[Project Name].currentmember, [Measures].[Spent])
SELECT { [Measures].[Spent],[Measures].[rnTotal] } ON COLUMNS, [Project].[Project Name]..[Project Name] * [Milestones].[Milestone].[Milestone] * [Milestone_Date].[Date]  from [ProjCube]  
It is returning the all member for the [Milestone_Date].[Date]